# Rows with name and nearest wealthy ancestor

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursion

How do you return not just all people and ancestors, but all people with only their nearest ancestor that happens to be loaded?

I've written a bunch of recursive queries before, but this one has me perplexed and fascinated. The illustration shows the hierarchy.

I promise this isn't a homework problem :).

[image]

Here's the test data:

```
create table test_people (
  id_person int unique not null
  ,ancestor_id_person int
  ,name varchar(10) unique not null
  ,wealth varchar(4) not null
);

insert into test_people (id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth) values
  (1, null, 'Abby', 'poor');
insert into test_people (id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth) values
  (2, 1, 'Barry', 'rich');
insert into test_people (id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth) values
  (3, 1, 'Dan', 'poor');
insert into test_people (id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth) values
  (4, 1, 'Elaine', 'poor');
insert into test_people (id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth) values
  (5, 1, 'Frank', 'rich');
insert into test_people (id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth) values
  (6, 1, 'Gary', 'poor');
insert into test_people (id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth) values
  (7, 2, 'Hank', 'poor');
insert into test_people (id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth) values
  (8, 3, 'Irene', 'poor');
insert into test_people (id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth) values
  (9, 4, 'Jack', 'rich');
insert into test_people (id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth) values
  (10, 5, 'Kelly', 'poor');
insert into test_people (id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth) values
  (11, 5, 'Nancy', 'poor');
insert into test_people (id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth) values
  (12, 6, 'Larry', 'poor');
insert into test_people (id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth) values
  (13, 6, 'Mike', 'poor');
insert into test_people (id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth) values
  (14, 7, 'Pearl', 'poor');
insert into test_people (id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth) values
  (15, 7, 'Rick', 'poor');
insert into test_people (id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth) values
  (16, 9, 'Steve', 'rich');
```

Here's the output I want:

```
NAME, NEAREST_WEALTHY_ANCESTOR
Abby, null
Barry, Barry
Dan, null
Elane, null
Frank, Frank
Gary, null
Hank, Barry
Irene, null
Jack, Jack
Kelly, Frank
Nancy, Frank
Larry, null
Mike, null
Pearl, Barry
Rick, Barry
Steve, Steve
```

Here's my latest (REALLY wrong) attempt:

```
with ancestors as (
  select 1 as level, id_person, ancestor_id_person, name, wealth
  from test_people
  where id_person = 1
  UNION ALL
  select parent.level + 1, child.id_person, child.ancestor_id_person, child.name, child.wealth
  from ancestors as parent,
  test_people as child 
  where parent.id_person = child.ancestor_id_person
)
select T.id_person, A.ancestor_id_person, A.name, T.name, T.ancestor_id_person
from test_people as T
left outer join ancestors as A on T.ancestor_id_person = max(A.ancestor_id_person, A.id_person)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to, in your CTE, include a column for the name of a rich ancestor and for each row being processed, set it to the current name if that person is rich, otherwise pass the existing value through unchanged (Or null for the root rows if those people are poor):

```
WITH RECURSIVE ancestors AS
 (SELECT id_person, name
       , CASE wealth WHEN 'rich' THEN name ELSE NULL END AS nearest_wealthy_ancestor
  FROM test_people WHERE ancestor_id_person IS NULL
 UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id_person, t.name
       , CASE t.wealth WHEN 'rich' THEN t.name ELSE a.nearest_wealthy_ancestor END
  FROM test_people AS t JOIN ancestors AS a ON t.ancestor_id_person = a.id_person)
SELECT name, nearest_wealthy_ancestor FROM ancestors ORDER BY name;
```

```
name        nearest_wealthy_ancestor
----------  ------------------------
Abby        null
Barry       Barry
Dan         null
Elaine      null
Frank       Frank
Gary        null
Hank        Barry
Irene       null
Jack        Jack
Kelly       Frank
Larry       null
Mike        null
Nancy       Frank
Pearl       Barry
Rick        Barry
Steve       Steve
```

---

Note: This query will benefit from an index on `test_people(ancestor_id_person)` And your `id_person` column should be an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` one for best performance with sqlite.